# Cosmos DB SQL API NOT IN operator taking a List WithParameter(List<t>) not working

Tags: c#, sql, azure-cosmosdb

```cs
var ids = IdsList.Select(pID => pID.ID).ToArray();

            var response= await MyService.GetByMyQuery(
                 new QueryDefinition(
                     "SELECT * FROM p WHERE p.id NOT IN(@ids)"
                 )
                 .WithParameter("@ids", string.Join(",", ids)),
            );
```

So this is not working. The operator returns all the items, instead of just the ones not in the list. In the cosmos DB SQL query editor i can easily do

```sql
SELECT * FROM p WHERE p.id NOT IN("id1","id2")
```

and it returns the expected results without any problems. SO i guess that the problem is in the code layer, the way I'm passing the ids to the WithParameter() menthod.

Any insights is greatly appreciated.

Comment: the query is different though, first one is filtering id while the later one has loan number

Comment: yes @Sajeetharan sorry it was a typo

Answer (score 5):

#### The problem

Your C# code is not sending multiple values as the `@ids` parameter, but a single string value, effectively like this:

```
SELECT * FROM p 
WHERE p.id NOT IN("id1, id2")
```

Since this compound id does not exist then it returns all items like you observed.

#### Solution

It may be possible with `IN` keyword as well, but I do know for sure that this pattern will work:

```
SELECT * FROM p 
WHERE NOT ARRAY_CONTAINS(@ids, p.id)
```

**NB!** Correct me if I'm mistaken, but most likely this condition will **NOT be served by index**. So, you may want to reconsider your design, unless your real case would have an additional good indexable predicate, or else it will be slow and costly.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but the query needs to return all the IDS that are not listed in the NOT IN() statement. For example if the dataset is ("a","b","c","d","e","f","g") and the query is  NOT IN ("a","d","b","c") it would return ["e","f","g"]. About the index, yes I can add an index, but my main concern is to make the query work first.

Comment: That's why there's that `NOT` in the solution query.

Comment: I think I misunderstood the query you wrote. `p.id` is not a parameter i would provide it is the from the `SELECT * FROM p` result set.  I will try this and if it works, mark it as a solution. Thanks in advance man.

Comment: I'm using the SQL API and it seems NOT ARRAY_CONTAINS is not a function i can use there.

Comment: Ehm.. it is: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/sql-query-array-contains. You have fixed your `.WithParameter(..)`, right?